# Estilização do Picker React Native

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Bom dia,

Estou usando Styled Components na estilização dos meus componentes em um app React Native, e estou tentando colocar uma borda colorida e arrendondada no meu Picker, mas o mesmo é renderizado sem a estilização. O código que estou usando é o seguinte:

```
const InputSexo = styled.Picker`
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
border: 1px solid #7b70e6;
width: 50%;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 15px;
color: #7b70e6;
```

`;

Estou desenvolvendo esse app usando o Expo para testar no meu celular com sistema Android.

Comment: Crie um [Exemplo mínimo reproduzivel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) assim será mais facil alguem ajudá-lo

Answer (score 0):

Basta criar uma view com a estilização que deseja e utilizá-la envolvendo o o componente picker. Isso para um projeto android, no iOS o picker possui um comportamento diferente.